# How to Add Authentication in Node Js API?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

Created API using below Tutorials: https://www.callicoder.com/node-js-express-mongodb-restful-crud-api-tutorial/

**How to add Authentication (outh) in this existing api?**

Creating api using : mongoDB + Node Js + Express JS

End goal is create a secure api using Node js.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a valid question to ask IMO because this could just google for it. Anyways, this article should give you a start: https://medium.com/p/d48369e7e6d4/

Answer (score 4):

You can use JSON web tokens(jwt) to secure the APIs. You have to make an endpoint through which you can generate a jwt token and after this, you can pass the token in headers before calling any of your API. Now make a middleware that can fetch the token from the headers and can verify it using jwt.verify() method.

You can follow the given link for better understanding:-
https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-es6-api-with-json-web-tokens

Hope this helps!